# Beam support of confluent schema registry and avro messages

Tags: python, apache-kafka, apache-beam

I am trying to setup a Beam pipeline to read from Kafka using **python API**. I am able to setup consumer config and topic(s). How to update the pipeline to use the confluent schema registry and to define the Avro message value deserializer?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [beam dynamically decode avro record using schema registry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61943251/beam-dynamically-decode-avro-record-using-schema-registry)

Comment: I tried the approach but getting AvroException due to the Enum usage in the Schema. However, I would like to receive as 'SpecificRecord' type not as 'GenericRecord'

Answer (score 0):

You can provide a key, value deserializers using the [Python API](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/dd20b4fd7547d5421eeae7ef0d1d62c3e3d6727a/sdks/python/apache_beam/io/kafka.py#L140) but the types this interface can return are limited (currently only byte and integer values). Deserializers that return Java types (for example `GenericRecord`) do not make much sense for Python. Will it be possible to use the byte deserializer (default) and process returned bytes using a Beam Python transform ? Also Beam Kafka transforms do not provide in-built support for connecting to the Confluent Schema registry but you might do so from a Beam `ParDo` transform (using a Kafka client library).

Comment: I tried to setup a simple pipeline to read the kafka records and log the records as described in [link](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/python/apache_beam/examples/kafkataxi/kafka_taxi.py). I don't see any log output and I am using DirectRunner. The Expansion service is automatically started and also runs the apache/beam_java11_sdk:2.29.0 image. Is DirectRunner not compatible for KafkaIO? or only PortableRunner is preferred?